# Use CSS3 or Javascript to add &raquo; to a link on hover

Tags: css, rollover

For my menu of a website I want to add text-decoaration on a:hover to be the » sign/symbol.

I tried it like this:

```
.navbar .nav > li:before > a:hover {
    content: "&raquo;";
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

like a different question suggested, but what displays is the text not the symbol and in its active state. is my CSS wrong or is there a way to do this through Javascript with a rollOver?

And here is my HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="brand" href="#">Rapid Newsletter Plus</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#packages">Packages</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav pull-right">
                            <li><a href="http://plus.rapidnewsletter.com">&raquo; my Account</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

UPDATE: I tweaked my CSS a lil bit and now the >> shows up in it's text form but it's not translating to the symbol >>. Any thoughts?

```
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover:before {
    content: "&raquo;";
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to add an "end of quotation mark" on hover?

Comment: It's not an "end of quotation mark" it's the >> symbol. Or at least that's what my code is translating it to.

Comment: You can't use entities, you'll have to use escaped unicode instead.

Comment: And what is that, or how might I go about doing that?

Comment: A bit of Google and boom! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Why not just use the `»` in the CSS? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HedBM/

Comment: @MagdaleneB. — The » symbol **is** an ["end of quotation mark"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to be in Unicode.

```
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover:before {
    content: "\00BB";
    color: #fff;
}
```

https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/ - For future reference convert HTML to various different codes including Unicode here. The bottom right box, called CSS escapes, is the correct one for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you can't use HTML named entities (or HTML numeric entities) so `&raquo;`, `&#187;` and `&#xbb;` will not be understood, they're for HTML, not CSS.

In CSS, you can specify that character using the escape sequence `\BB`, i.e. the hexadecimal unicode encoding for that character.